# Table View Remains Blank Despite Core Data "Successfully Saved!"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[My first Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNN1M.png)

Then I go on to login screen by clicking "Sign In" button.

[My Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl51g.png)

Next I go on to the screen with the table view... This is how it looks when I successfully login:

[Table View Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHpLH.png)

Next I click on the add resident icon(the small icon with the person and the plus sign) and I get this page in which I can register a resident.

[Register Resident Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARkAG.png)

Next, what should happen is, when I click the add button, it should "successfully save" my core data and it should automatically dismiss this view and got back to the "Table View Screen" (Previous Picture). But it doesn't! When it goes to the Table View Screen, it should register the new resident with the name "Bob" and the Age "45" saved in my core data successfully. Please help me fix these 2 problems...

This is the view controller in which my data is saved using core data. I get "successfully saved" when I click the "Add" button.

```
//  ResidentViewController.swift
//  77 Safety Updater
//
//  Created by Tejas Ravishankar on 17/04/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Tejas Ravishankar. All rights reserved.
//
//MARK:- Import Modules
import UIKit
import CoreData
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

class ResidentViewController: UIViewController {
//MARK:- Variables
    var residentCount : Int = 0
    var travelSwitchIsOn : Bool = false
    var movedInSwitchIsOn : Bool = false
    var stateColor : UIColor = .systemGreen
    var name : String = ""
    var age : Int = 0
    var type : Int = 0
    var risk : String = ""
//MARK:- IB Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var riskLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var workingSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var movedInSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var movedInLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var yesLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var noLabel: UILabel!
//MARK:- Add Button Action
    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        residentCount += 1
        let ageText = ageTextField.text
        if ageText!.count >= 4
        {
            ageTextField.text = ""
            ageTextField.placeholder = "Invalid Age!"
        }
        name = nameTextField.text!
        age = Int(ageText!)!
        travelSwitchIsOn = workingSwitch.isOn
        movedInSwitchIsOn = movedInSwitch.isOn
        if movedInSwitchIsOn == true || travelSwitchIsOn == true
        {
            risk = "Medium"
        }
        else if movedInSwitchIsOn == true && travelSwitchIsOn == true
        {
            risk = "High"
        }
        else
        {
            risk = "Low"
        }
        if age <= 4
        {
            stateColor = .systemRed
        }
        if age <= 20
        {
            stateColor = .systemGreen
        }

        else if age >= 55 && age <= 90
        {
            stateColor = .systemRed
        }

        else if age > 90
        {
            stateColor = .systemPurple
        }
        if nameTextField.text != "" && ageTextField.text != ""
        {
            saveData { (complete) in
                   if complete
                   {
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                   }
                   }
            }
        }

//MARK:- Core Data Save Function
    func saveData(completion:(_ finished:Bool) -> ())
    {
        guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
            else
        {
            return
        }


        let data = UserData(context: managedContext)
        data.name = name
        data.age = Int32(age)
        data.risk = risk

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            print("Successfully Saved!")
            completion(true)
            }
        catch {
            debugPrint("Save Failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
              }
    }

//MARK:- Resident Type Action
    @IBAction func residentTypeChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl)
    {
        let type = sender.selectedSegmentIndex

        if type == 0
        {
            movedInSwitch.isHidden = true
            movedInLabel.isHidden = true
            yesLabel.isHidden = true 
            noLabel.isHidden = true
        }
        if type == 1
        {
            movedInSwitch.isHidden = false
            movedInLabel.isHidden = false
            yesLabel.isHidden = false
            noLabel.isHidden = false
        }

    }

//MARK:- When App Screen Loads Up
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        movedInSwitch.isHidden = true
        movedInLabel.isHidden = true
        riskLabel.text = ""
        ageTextField.delegate = self
        yesLabel.isHidden = true
        noLabel.isHidden = true
    }
}

extension ResidentViewController : UITextFieldDelegate
{
    @IBAction func ageTextField(_ sender: UITextField)
     {
        let age = Int(ageTextField.text!)

        if age! <= 4
        {
            riskLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemGreen
            stateColor = .systemRed
            riskLabel.text = "High Risk Host!"
        }
        if age! <= 20
        {
            riskLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemGreen
            stateColor = .systemGreen
            riskLabel.text = "Low Risk Host!"
        }

        else if age! >= 55 && age! <= 90
        {
            riskLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemRed
            stateColor = .systemRed
            riskLabel.text = "High Risk Host!"
        }

        else if age! > 90
        {
            riskLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemPurple
            stateColor = .systemPurple
            riskLabel.text = "Very High Risk Host!"
        }

     }
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        ageTextField.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if ageTextField.text != ""
        {
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            textField.placeholder = "Type Something!"
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

> This is the table view controller which contains the configuration of the cell and the table! I have also fetched the data in this view controller. In the output: I get "successfully fetched!" Ignore the login view controller.swift as it just contains my authentication using user defaults... There are no parts of CoreData in that file...

```
//
//  StatisticsViewController.swift
//  77 Safety Updater
//
//  Created by Tejas Ravishankar on 17/04/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Tejas Ravishankar. All rights reserved.
//
//MARK:- Import Modules
import UIKit
import CoreData

class StatisticsViewController: UIViewController
{
    var details : [UserData] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var informationTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        informationTableView.delegate = self
        informationTableView.dataSource = self
        informationTableView.isHidden = false
        informationTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "InformationTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "informationCell")
    }

    func fetchData(completion:(_ complete:Bool) -> ())
    {
        guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
        else
        {
            return
        }

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<UserData>(entityName: "UserData")
        do {
            try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as![UserData]
            print("Successfully Fetched!")
            completion(true)
        }
        catch
        {
            debugPrint("Failed To Fetch: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(false)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.fetchData { (complete) in
            if complete
            {
                if details.count >= 1
                {
                    informationTableView.isHidden = true
                }
                else
                {
                    informationTableView.isHidden = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension StatisticsViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        details.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = informationTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "informationCell") as! InformationTableViewCell
        let userDetail = details[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(userDetail)
        return cell
    }
}
```

This is my table view cell cocoa touch class in which I configure the data stored in the cells.

```
//
//  InformationTableViewCell.swift
//  77 Safety Updater
//
//  Created by Tejas Ravishankar on 26/04/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Tejas Ravishankar. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

class InformationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var ageLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
    {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    func configureCell(_ detail : UserData)
    {
        self.nameLabel.text = detail.name
        self.ageLabel.text = String(describing: detail.age)
    }
}
```

Thanks A Lot!!!

Comment: I think the issue in your `if details.count >= 1` logic, probably you want to write `if details.count >= 0`.

Comment: I tried that... The table appears even when the details.count is zero and apart from that there is no change.